# Desktop Internal Drive Disconnecting

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, sata, computer-building

After installing a secondary hard drive, it randomly disconnects under heavy read/write stress. By this i mean, the drive would disappear (no longer visible on Windows Explorer or Disk Management). Sometimes it would reappear on restarts, other times I'd need to plug it into a different SATA cable to get it recognized again.

The first few times this happened I assumed it was a faulty drive, or it was getting old. So i replaced it with a brand new SSD.

Downloading a few games from Steam and playing, the same thing started to happen again with the new Drive.

This secondary drive is connected to one of the extra SATA cables and power cables that were available inside the machine (its designed to be expanded to 3 or 4 drives). I also tried swapping those cables..

After this didn't work, I wondered if the factory 500w power supply wasn't enough for the GTX 980TI so i bought a 750w EVGA power supply. Nope, problem still there.

**Attempted Fixes**

- Tried replacing the hard drive itself
- Tried using different SATA and power cables internally
- Tried reformatting the drive
- Replaced with a higher watt power supply 500w -> 750w
- Ran HWInfo to ensure temperatures weren't getting too high
- I'm not overclocking, just the standard settings the PC shipped with

**Part List**

- Model: HP Omen 750-170se
- Motherboard: HP 2B4B -Intel Z170 (Skylake PCH-H)
- Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
- CPU: Intel Core i7-6700
- GPU: GTX 980ti
- Power Supply: EVGA 750 N1, 750W
- Primary Hard Drive: 1TB Samsung SSD 2.5"
- Secondary Hard Drive: Team Group GX1 2.5" 960GB SATA III Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)

**Other Ideas?**
Something to do with the grounding of the cable? I noticed the primary hard drive has one attached to its SATA connection but the other cables don't, see image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJVPX.jpg

Comment: My thought was electrical noise, and that seems more likely when I saw that the other drive is ungrounded. A short ground strap to the same location used by other ground connections might help... and is easy to test.

Comment: Might be a problem with the motherboard. Bad connector?

Comment: I would first check for tensions of the motherboard in the case;
I'd take out the motherboard and put it on an even surface and check again

Comment: How many SATA drives can you connect to the mainboard? Usually it's at least 4... Did you try a different port yet? Did you check the BIOS/UEFI yet? Which SATA standards do the HD and the HD-controller support? Did you try a benchmark/test that only puts load on the HD components and not anything else?

Comment: Your old 500w power supply was definitely not powerful enough. There is a very good chance your motherboard got damaged from it. Maybe you should verify the capacitors on your motherboard. Something very similar happened to me a few months ago and lost my Mobo + 1 Hdd... Make sure to backup your important stuff regularly!